# How could I export this animation?

Tags: export

I would like to export the following animation as a .avi or gif or basically anything. I tried, but couldn't: I either get a very sloppy video (meaning: about 1fps) or the DefaultDurations  do not match. The animate[] generates the desirable effect. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.
UPDATE: I can get it to export a smooth avi, the problem is that it does not consider the DefaultDurations, plus it modifies the 2 sliders not at the sime time, but rather subsequentally.

```
    Animate[{ m = 1; cc = 0.1; k = 0.1;
    soln = NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + cc*x'[t] + k*x[t] == 0, {x[0] == disp,  x'[0]== 0}}, {x[t], x'[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
    solnx[1, t_] = x[t] /. soln[[1, 1]];
    solnx[2, t_] = x'[t] /. soln[[1, 2]];
    With[{l = 2 + solnx[1, run]},
    a = {{xend, yend}, {xend, yend - .2}};
    b = {{xend, yend - .2}, {xend + 1, yend - .3}}; c = 
    Table[{ xend + Cos[\[Pi]*(n - 1)], yend - (.3 + (n - 1)*l/10)}, {n, 1,10}];
    d = {{xend - 1, yend - (.9 l + .3)}, {xend, yend - (.9 l + .4)}};
    e = {{xend, yend - (.9 l + .4)}, {xend, yend - (.9 l + .6)}};
    thirdplot = Plot[yend - (.9*(2 + solnx[1, t]) + 2.6), {t, 0, 100}, PlotLabel -> Pozíció, PlotRange -> {-5, 1.5}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}];
    follow3 = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red,  Point[{run, (yend - 0.9*(2 + solnx[1, run]) + 2.6)}]}];
    GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[{Line[a], Line[b], Line[c], Line[d], Line[e], RGBColor[.49, 0, 0],  Rectangle[{xend - 1, yend - (.9 l + .6)}, {xend + 1, yend - (.9 l + 2.6)}]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-4, 4}} ], 
  Show[thirdplot, follow3]}}, ImageSize -> {800, 800}]]}, {disp, -1, 3, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, DefaultDuration -> 3}, {{run, 0}, 0, 100,DefaultDuration -> 10, AnimationRepetitions -> 1},  ContentSize -> {700, 700}, AnimationRunning -> True]
```

Comment: Can you post the failed attempts? `Export["animation.gif, tab]` should work (where `tab` is the list of images).

Comment: Sorry, I figured the wrong quality part- it was due to a = declaration instead of := . The problem now is that in the exported video, the two sliders go from 0 to the desired value, THEN BACK TO ZERO, plus they do not move at the same time, as in the Animate.It seems that it didn't consider the DefaultDuration part.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!